# A robust metric in the presence of class imbalance

Tags: classification, multiclass-classification, model-evaluations, class-imbalance, imbalanced-learn

When evaluating the performance of a multiclass classification problem, on a highly imbalanced dataset, what is the most robust metric for this purpose?

I read a paper that states:

> "Average precision is a robust metric in the presence of class
>   imbalance since it excludes the ‘true negatives’ constituent in
>   specificity, focusing instead on precision, or positive predictive
>   value."

The confusing part, for me, is the applied methodology in this paper. They used balancing techniques (SMOTE, class_weigh, random sampling) to oversample minority classes, but they are still concerned about the evaluation metrics and 'true negatives'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For evaluating the classification of a highly imbalanced, there are several measures that you may consider. Remember, that in such a problem we would prefer a measure that is not biased towards one of the classes but gives similar importance to both classes.

Methods for evaluating classifiers could be divided into two types: singular assessment measures where the evaluation is given for a specific threshold (i.e. trade-off) and area-under-curve (AUC) analyses where a range of thresholds is considered.

The **F-measure** combines precision and recall. Precision is sensitive to data distribution as it combines values from the two rows of the confusion-matrix hence, **as the difference between the numbers of negative and positive instances gets larger, the influence of the positive class (minority) gets smaller**. Recall, on the other hand, is not sensitive to data distribution since it does not refer to the negative class at all. Affected by the precision, the F-measure must be sensitive to class distribution as well. The F-measure gives higher importance to the correct classification of positive instances, a change in the TNR value will influence the F-measure value less than a change in TPR. This is explained by the impact of the recall, which considers only the correct classification of positive class instances.

The **Geometric Mean** (G-measure, GM) combines TPR and TNR, denoting the accuracy rates measured on both classes separately. The GM is **independent** of the class sizes, indicating the relative part of correctly classified instances in each class **regardless of the degree of imbalance**. That is, the GM is not influenced by the imbalance between the classes, The GM relates to the performance on both classes with the same importance since it is a harmonic mean of the TPR & TNR and their effect is symmetrical. Higher values of GM are achieved when the accuracies on both classes are high and similar. For example, a higher GM value is accomplished when accuracies on both classes are equal to 0.5 than when one is 0.6 and the other 0.4.

The **ROC-AUC** is based on the TPR and FPR, which is 1-TNR, and hence have the same reasoning for suiting such problems as the GM.

The **PR-AUC**, precision-recall curve, are also useful for highly imbalanced data and also is robust for changes in the balance of classes (addition of samples). I've found this **[article](https://acutecaretesting.org/en/articles/precision-recall-curves-what-are-they-and-how-are-they-used)** very useful for understanding AUC measures and the benefits of each one of them.

The AUC analysis provides a more generic evaluation however, in most cases it will not give the best solution when a specific trade-off is to be considered. The AUC is only relevant if your classifier output is not discrete but continues.

For more reading and comparisons you may use Prof. Haibo He **[lectures](https://www.ele.uri.edu/faculty/he/research/ImbalancedLearning/ImbalancedLearning_lecturenotes.pdf)** which are very comprehensive and useful.

Comment: GM is not influenced by class imbalance, and also you stated that ROC-AUC also have the same reasoning for suiting such problems as the GM, but isn't ROC-AUC sensitive to class imbalance?

Answer (score 0):

F1-score or G-measure should be fine for imbalanced dataset.

To evaluate model to negative prediction consider negative predictive value or specificity.

Source:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity